# Snail on an extensible mat:

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

An extensible mat initially measures L meters long. A snail has decided to crawl it entirely. Each day, the snail progresses one meter and sleeps at night. However, every night, while the snail rests, the mat elongates by two meters, which are evenly distributed over the entire length.

1-  If $L=4$ meters, how long will it take for the snail to reach the end of the mat?

2-  Let $T(L)$ be the number of days required to reach the end. Show that as $L$ approaches infinity, the limit of $T(L)/L$ equals $\frac{e^2-1}{2}$

```
.
```

For 1) I used this program

Let

```
"u": variable representing the distance covered by the snail

"n": variable representing the number of days elapsed

"u=u+1+2*(u+1)/L": updates the distance covered by the snail 
"L=L+2": updates the length of the rubber band 


u = 0
n = 0
L = 4

while u < L:
    n = n + 1
    u = u + 1 + 2 * (u + 1) / L
    L = L + 2
    print([n, u, L])
```

output

```
[1, 1.5, 6]
[2, 3.3333333333333335, 8]
[3, 5.416666666666668, 10]
[4, 7.700000000000001, 12]
[5, 10.150000000000002, 14]
[6, 12.742857142857146, 16]
[7, 15.460714285714289, 18]
[8, 18.289682539682545, 20]
[9, 21.2186507936508, 22]
[10, 24.238528138528146, 24]
```

So on the 10th day, the snail will have traveled the entire length of the tape.

I need some help  to solve 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have already shown that there is a recursion relation that connects the distance traversed by the snail at the end of the $n$-th day with the distance traversed by the next day, given by

$$D_{n+1}=\frac{L+2(n+1)}{L+2n}(D_n+1)$$

This is a linear first order difference equation that can be solved by quadrature. One can show that the solution when $D_0=0$ is given by

$$D_n+1=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{L+2n}{L+2k}$$

Here, we are interested in the smallest number $T=T(L)$ such that the snail at the beginning of the $T$-th day has reached the end of the carpet, which can be written as $D_T+1>L+2T$. Basically this requires the smallest solution to the inequality to be found:

$$T(L)=\inf_n\left\{n\in\mathbb{N} ~~\Bigg|~~\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{L+2k}>1\right\}$$

For any $L$, there exists a large enough $n_0$ such that the inequality is satisfied, given the divergence of $D_n$ as $n\to\infty$ and because of the structure of the natural numbers an infimum of the set of numbers satisfying the above inequality always exists.

Explicit solutions are impossible to write, however we can make an asymptotic estimate of the stopping time as $L\to \infty$. First note the trivial bound $T(L)>L-1$.Furthermore, notice that the Euler-MacLaurin formula yields the asymptotic series

$$\sum_{k=0}^{T(L)}\frac{1}{L+2k}-\int_0^{T(L)}\frac{dx}{L+2x}=\frac{L+T(L)}{L(L+2T(L))}+\mathcal{O}(L^{-2})$$

which along with the trivial bound above shows that the sum and integral are asymptotically equivalent, and hence guarantees the existence, finiteness and equality of the following limits

$$\lim_{L\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{T(L)}\frac{1}{L+2k}~~,~~\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_0^{T(L)}\frac{dx}{L+2x}$$

if the limit $\lim_{L\to\infty}T(L)/L$ exists and is finite (more work needs to be done to justify this statement). Furthermore, we note that the inequality can be satisfied more and more tightly for increasing $L$, since the individual terms of the series approach zero and hence the increments are tiny, but since the series is guaranteed to exceed any value for large enough $n$, we are guaranteed to be able to approximate any number arbitrarily well by summing terms of the above series with increasing $L$.   This allows us to justify solving instead the asymptotic equality

$$\lim_{L\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{T(L)}\frac{1}{L+2k}=\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_0^{T(L)}\frac{dx}{L+2x}=\lim_{L\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1+
\frac{2T(L)}{L}\right)=1$$

which implies the limit

$$\lim_{L\to\infty}\frac{T(L)}{L}=\frac{e^2-1}{2}$$

Comment: Very well explained, thank you